# Position of the configuration files of TexMaker

Tags: macos

Someone could provide information about the position inside the pc of the configuration files for the application TeXMaker. I can't find any file in the home directory.

More precisely, I'm looking for the `.ini` file in order to make permanent changes in the path.

Comment: if you want to find files related to TexMaker, run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` to update your locate database and run `locate TexMaker` to find the files related to your program (it won't show all of them but most)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `texmaker.ini` file is created in the user's home and it's stored in:

```
~/.config/xm1
```

If I do

```
ls ~/.config/xm1/
```

the result is

```
texmaker.ini        texmakerapp.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to access your .ini file in texmaker options>manage settings file>save a copy

This creates a .ini file and allows you to save it anywhere you like. You can then manipulate this file [use this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio) page as reference copying and pasting which is what I did. Make sure you only use texmaker code if config texmaker and texstudio if texstudio.

From there options>manage settings file>replace settings file by new one (one that you manipulated)

Hope this helps!